# Data is not being displayed in in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am displaying some data in React. I read this data from localStorage and display in FlatList.
Data is there in array, but not getting displayed.

**cartItems** is the array which have this data and this array is passed to FlatList.

```
cartItems = [{"food":"bread","foodPrice":"Rs. 100"},{"food":"bread","foodPrice":"Rs. 100"}, 
{"food":"bread","foodPrice":"Rs. 100"},{"food":"bread","foodPrice":"Rs. 100"}, 
{"food":"bread","foodPrice":"Rs. 100"}]
```

But no data is being displayed.

Cart.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    FlatList,
    View,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text
} from "react-native";

export default class Cart extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cartItems: []            
        };

        let orderArray = localStorage.getItem("Foods") // Get previously stored food items
        
        let cartItems = []
        if (orderArray !== null) {
            //cartItems = [...JSON.parse(orderArray)]
            this.setState({cartItems: [...JSON.parse(orderArray)]})
        }
        
        console.log("Cart: cartItems = "+JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    }


    renderItemComponent = (data) =>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: data.item.url }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

    ItemSeparator = () => <View style={{
        height: 2,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
    }}
    />



    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.cartItems}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    
                        <TouchableOpacity >
                            <Text >{item.food}</Text>
                            <Text >{item.foodPrice}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    }
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ItemSeparator}


                />
            </View>)     
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 300,
        margin: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        borderRadius: 6,
    },
    image: {
        height: '100%',
        borderRadius: 4,
    },
});
```

What can be the root cause of this problem.
It seems that, there is very small issue, but not able to find yet.

Comment: React use `states` to trigger re-render. So, you should assign data into `cartItems` by `this.setState({cartItems: [...JSON.parse(orderArray)]})`

Comment: @kiuQ: console.log() was initially displaying data. But after change suggested by you, it is showing empty array in console. Edited the question as per your answer.

Comment: You are assigning data into `state.cartItems` instead of the variable `cartItems` you created. So your `console.log(cartItems)` will still print empty array. Also, setState only take effect after the function is done, therefore, you won't see the data even you use `console.log(this.state.cartItems)`.

Comment: @Android This code `let cartItems = []` is irrelevant now as `cartItems` never gets updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component is not re-rendering after `cartItems` is set like this :

```
cartItems = [...JSON.parse(orderArray)]
```

It is taking  `cartItems` as an empty array from initial state and showing no data, so you should use `this.setState` to re-render the component, the correct way would be like this :

```
this.setState({cartItems: [...JSON.parse(orderArray)]})
```

**Update :**

- now you are setting the data correctly,
- but when you are setting the
  data is important.

if your data is available from local storage initially then it will work for your code, but if the data is not available initially in local storage, then you need to set them correctly using

`componentDidMount()` or `componentDidUpdate()` depending on your app scenario (working logic).

then only the data in local storage updation will reflect in you component.

you can also read more details here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

also check `The Component Lifecycle`

Comment: Hi, initially in console, this array was having data. After your change , console shows empty array. Edited question based on your answer. Kindly check again. Is that correct?

Comment: i have updated my answer with more info, please check now.